# Problems understanding constructors like the one in ArrayList.class

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

While coding I was trying to declare a class that can create an arraylist of arraylists, but soon enough I found it hard to define a proper constructor for my class. I wanted to define some methods for me to handle the huge outer arraylist(1000*1000), but I might be affected by C and always tried to use something like structdef.

How should I define my class? I guess declaring every lines seperatedly is not a wise choice, and I don't want to use 2D arraylist directly. Besides, how should I define a constructor to get an object that is an 2D arraylist?

//Update here
Below is my code example:

```java
class farbicMap {
    //attribute
    ArrayList<Integer> farbicUnit = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //constructor
    farbicMap () {
        for (int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
            farbicUnit.add(0);
        }//this gives an arraylist with size of 100
        //I want to use the above arraylist to construct another list here
    }

    //method
    setUnitValue(int v) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Seems that I didn't really understand the concept of class... I wanted to use the class to represent a map with some nodes. Now that's much clearer to me.

Comment: Can you show some code? Because it is quite unclear what you are trying to do. "I was trying to declare a class that can create an arraylist of arraylists,". I class don't _create_ stuff. It _represents_ things. What is your class supposed to represent?

Comment: @Chien , Can you share your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I understood your consern:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board(1000, 1000);
        board.put(1, 2, "X");
        Object x = board.get(1, 2);
        System.out.println("x = " + x);
    }
}


class Board {

    private final int xSize;
    private final int ySize;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> board = new ArrayList<>();

    public Board(int xSize, int ySize) {
        this.xSize = xSize;
        this.ySize = ySize;
        for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++) {
            board.add(getListOfNulls());
        }
    }


    public Object get(int x, int y) {
        return board.get(x).get(y);
    }

    public void put(int x, int y, Object toAdd) {
        List<Object> xs = board.get(x);
        if (xs == null) {
            xs = getListOfNulls();
        }
        xs.add(y, toAdd);
    }

    private ArrayList<Object> getListOfNulls() {
        ArrayList<Object> ys = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < ySize; j++) {
            ys.add(null);
        }
        return ys;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I'm looking for, but a lot better than my version :)

Comment: @Chien you're welcome, if it's true you can click on a grey chek mark to accept this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Array if size is fixed.

Comment: That does not answer the question.